# In Typescript 2, how can I use a local definition file?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm just trying to get Typescript 2 to use a local definition file provided by me, for a javascript library I installed through NPM.

First, I installed MockDate:

```
npm i --save-dev mockdate
```

Then, I attempted to import it via

```
import MockDate from 'mockdate'
```

Only to be told it couldn't find it. From here, I've created local definitions, I've `declare module 'mockdate'`, I've done

```
declare module MockDate {
  function set(date: Date): void
}
```

at the top of the file- and no matter what I do, I continue to receive(from `atom-typescript`) "Cannot find module 'mockdate'".

Answer (score 3):

Almost there! You need to write:

```
declare module 'mockdate' {
  function set(date: Date): void
}
```

And make sure this d.ts file is picked up by your tsconfig.

Comment: I think the latest version of vs code automatically picks up all .d.ts files in the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. write a .d.ts file
2. import .d.ts file to your project with Triple-Slash Directives

[Triple-Slash Directives code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqfVo.png)

3. then you can get your type info in the project

Comment: thanks, but where can I find the official documents about this?

Comment: this is still not working for me, i guess i must missed a lot knowledge that people already knew on this issue, thanks again